# send mail and insert to database play framwork

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

im using play framework 2.1.1 and java ,
im submitting a form and i  can insert the data to the database,
also im sending mail by using the wonderful    [mailer plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer)

what will be the best  way to perform both  action paralleled instead of  one after the other ,
should i use     [ThreadPools](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools)  or there is a  more simple solution.

**UPDATE SOLUTION :**

this is how i solve it in the end

```
private static void sendMailHelper(final UserData formData) {
    Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
              Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
              new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 SendMail.sendMail(formData);
                }
              }, Akka.system().dispatcher());
}
```

i sent mail 10 sec after the user submit the form

Comment: first save to DB, then try to send, most probably it will be safer approach. In case of problem with sending you'll keep it in DB anyway.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Scala, then these pages should help you:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html
- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaAsync

If you are using Java, then these pages should help you:

- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaAsync (as Carsten pointed out)

You could also use Akka Actors, check this page:

- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaAkka